Helm Release name and service discovery
I am using a redis chart from a repository (bitnami) as subchart for my application deployment. After installation with say, release name = "tiger", the redis service is named "tiger-redis-master". This appears to be a common practice of prefixing the release name to avoid collisions.
The problem now is how to propagate this deployment-dependent service name to the application. In the past, I would define in values.yaml
   env:
      - name: REDIS_SERVICE_URL
        value: redis://redis-master:6379

and my application template just iterates over env and echoes these values.
Now it seems I need to special-case my template just to accommodate the fact the service name is deployment-dependent, something like:
   {{- with .Values.env }}
   env:
       {{- range $envname, $envval := . }}
       - name: {{ $envname }}
         value: {{ $envval | quote }}
       {{- end }}
   {{- end }}
     - name: REDIS_SERVICE_URL
       value: redis://{{ .Release.Name }}-redis-master:6379

But now my application template is not generally reusable.
I understand there is an option to use
redis:
   fullnameOverride: redis-master

such that the service name is static but I have been told this is not good practice
This is such a common use-case, I don't understand why these isn't well-known prescribed way to do this?
Have tried using fullnameOverride option and that works but seems to be discouraged
Now using a custom template for my application but that does not seem to be an extensible solution

I don't really like the pattern of writing out blocks of Kubernetes YAML directly in Helm values, FWIW; that's supposed to be administrator-level configuration, and if you're going to just write out YAML there, you may as well directly edit the Kubernetes manifest files.  The example you have of providing $REDIS_SERVICE_URL in your template file directly matches what I'd do, maybe giving a specific install-time override if Redis isn't being installed as a chart dependency.
